# Offline version of Stack Exchange

Tags: support, stack-exchange

Is there a offline version of the Stack Exchange platform to download to run on an internal network?

Answer (score 1):

[Stack Overflow Enterprise is available](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise) for internal use, but it is really meant for larger organizations only. For public sites, there's a long list of similar Q&A platforms out there that you can host yourself: [Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones).